# Giving an AI a purpose to talk

Tags: natural-language-processing, algorithm, generative-model

I am trying to teach my AI to talk. The problem is I'm struggling to find a good scenario in which it needs to.

Some ideas I had were:
"Describe a geometric scene" - Then together with a parser we could see how close the generated instructions came to the official geometric language.

"Give another AI instructions of where to find some food" e.g. "Go straight on passed the box then turn left until you get to the tree. Look under the rock."

Another one might be "Find out more information about a scene by asking questions of another AI in order to navigate a scene blindfolded". This is quite an extreme example!

I need it to talk in formal English sentences (not some kind of made up secret langauge.)

Basically instead of just interpreting a language and following instructions, I want my AI to generate instructions.

So the things I want to teach it are the following:

- Ability to ask questions + ability to use the information gathered
- Ability to give instructions

Do you know of any projects like this?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this piece of news yesterday: ["This week, Microsoft Research threw down the gauntlet with the launch of a competition challenging researchers around the world to develop AI agents that can solve text-based games."](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/first-textworld-problems-microsoft-research-montreals-latest-ai-competition-is-really-cooking/) 
This seems to be an AI competition announced by Microsoft with the aim to create AI that can solve text-based games. This might give you some inspiration.